# SQL - Query - where not in select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Okay here is my SQL:-

```
SELECT Telephone, 
       Houseno, 
       Street, 
       Tostreet, 
       Passengername, 
       Acceptancedate 
FROM   Telephone 
WHERE  Acceptancedate !> '2014/05/01' 
       AND Telephone LIKE '011%' 
       AND ( Zoneno = '6' 
              OR Zoneno = '5' 
              OR Zoneno = '9' 
              OR Zoneno = '108' ) 
       AND Telephone = 'XXX' 
ORDER  BY Acceptancedate
```

This displays 5 records for this phone number.

However, if I change the `!>` to `>`

it shows 3 records.

The SQL I have is correct, but I only want to display the numbers IF this telephone number doesn't appear when `AcceptanceDate > '2014/05/01'` (as the phone numbers are not unique)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your use case? If you change operators in a where statement, then it's obvious to get different results, so what are you trying to say by changing !> to >?

Comment: Basically I want to display all the numbers from the above SQL, WHERE Telephone is not in the following query; SELECT * from Telephone WHERE Acceptancedata > '2014/05/01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude the telephone numbers that appear after a certain date

```
SELECT  Telephone, 
        Houseno, 
        Street, 
        Tostreet, 
        Passengername, 
        Acceptancedate 
FROM    Telephone AS t
WHERE   Telephone LIKE '011%' 
AND     Zoneno IN ('6', '5', '9', '108')
AND     Telephone = 'XXX' 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Telephone AS t2
            WHERE   t2.Telephone = t.Telephone
            AND     t2.Acceptancedate > '20140501' 
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the `where` clause like this:

```
WHERE  Acceptancedate <= '2014-05-01' AND
       Telephone LIKE '011%' AND
       Zoneno IN ('6', '5', '9', '108') AND
       Telephone = 'XXX'
```

This will not change the outcome, but here are the changes:

- `!<` is not a standard comparison operator.  Use `<=` which is clearer.
- I changed the format of the date to the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format
- I changed the comparison of `ZoneNo`s to use `IN` rather than `OR`

Also, I note two comparisons on `Telephone`.  The first is redundant.